# Open PFD files through PHP and Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, mysqli

I have an image upload system on my portfolio website that calls images from a database using PHP. Most of the files that are shown are images. Some of them however are PDF files and I would like to know how to open these PDF files in new windows as well as the images. Instead right now, it just downloads those PDF files to my computer. How do I fix this? This is my code:

```
?>

</div>
<ul class="media-list">
<?php
include "config.php"; //database connection
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM upload_data");
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()):
?>

 <?php   ?>

<div class="media">

 <a class="media-left" href="#">

 </a>
<div class="img">

  <a target="_blank" onclick="window.open('upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>','<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>')">

    <img width="300" height="200" src="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>"></a>  
</div>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the pdf in browser without downloading, the header should be,

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

Comment: That just downloads the file "filename.pdf" to my computer. Unless I'm implementing it wrong? Can you clarify how it's supposed to look like?

Comment: 1.How you implement that? 2 . Did you inspect headers in firebug or developer tool?

Comment: Try this, https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/forcing-a-pdf-or-doc-to-open-in-browser-rather-than-downloading

Comment: I was thinking about implementing that on my website, so that anyone visiting my website would see the pdf files in their browser, rather than the files being downloaded to their computer. Why would I need to edit 'my' virtual host files for that?

Comment: "Normally, Apache and WAMP servers have a MIME-type-to-file-extension association file (Config\Apache\mime.types) that sets the correct “Content-type” Header for PDF files. But sometimes, depending on the website’s configuration and where and how the PDF files are located and/or generated, the above Header configuration is required". YOU HAVE TO OVERWRITE HEADER THROUGH THAT VHOST CONFIG FOR PDF.